# Rigid families of $\{0,1\}$ matrices

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, linear-algebra

We know that there are many families of matrices over $\Bbb F_q$, $\Bbb R$ etc are rigid.
See http://mahdi.cheraghchi.info/talks/rigidity_talk.pdf

Do we know there are many families of rigid **REAL** matrices with alphabet $\{0,1\}$ or $\{-1,+1\}$ (note not same as $\Bbb F_2$)?

Comment: see e.g. Section 9 of [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9400115Y) by Pudlak and Roedl.